# Quickly is Not Packaging My Application?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I Can't Package my Quickly Command Line Application , The Following is The Error Output

`quickly package --verbose` shows the following output

```
    /host/cryptonite$ quickly package --verbose
running install_egg_info
Writing /tmp/tmp5mW39i/cryptonite-14.02.1.egg-info
Searching packages which provide required Python modules:
Can't update changelog.
An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with sudo, some of the operations may need root privileges.